# Mini cart js is not working properly the count is not showing some times

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, knockoutjs, mini-cart, magento2minicart

Minicart is not showing cart count properly at the time of not logging in. I had tried to show statically into the id condition but the when loading the 0 is shown after load it is not showing, I think the problem is that from the **getCartParam('summary_count')** the value is not passing if there is no zero is coming, it is not showing inside the if condition I will give the  minicart js code below please suggest some solution for this.

And please tell how to check the null in knockout Js magento 2.3?

```
<span class="counter qty empty"
              data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false }, blockLoader: isLoading">
            <span class="counter-number"><!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko --></span>
            <span class="counter-label">
            <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
                <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->

            <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') == 0 -->
                0
                <!-- ko i18n: 'items' --><!-- /ko -->   
            <!-- /ko -->
            </span>
            <span class="counter-number"><!-- ko text: **cart().summary_count || 0** --><!-- /ko --></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is :

```
<!-- ko if: (getCartLineItemsCount() === 0) -->
                    <span translate="'No Item in Cart'"/>
<!--/ko-->

<!-- ko if: (getCartLineItemsCount() === 1) -->
                    <span translate="'Item in Cart'"/>
<!--/ko-->

<!-- ko if: (getCartLineItemsCount() > 1) -->
                    <span translate="'Items in Cart'"/>
<!--/ko-->
```